# 10 gbps ethernet adapter (Intel 82599 / ixgbe) on slower network - "Link is not ready"

Tags: networking, linux-networking

Perhaps this is a newbie problem - I know nothing about 10 gbps networking hardware. I purchased a motherboard for building a new computer and I'm trying to get it online. Its onboard 10 Gbps adapter doesn't get past "Link is not ready". The networking setup is fine - I just tested it with my laptop. But the computer doesn't see the link, whether with a stock linux setup or with the Intel ixgbe driver installed. This despite the cable lighting up when plugged in.

The ixgbe docs are very confusing to me, but it sounds like a person may need to do something special to make it work with a non-10gbps network. Any thoughts on what I should try?

---

Ed:

```
# ethtool eno1
Settings for eno1:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised link modes:  100000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: Other
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: no
```

Um, wow, that doesn't look good. Especially only "supported ports: fibre"; I'm 99% sure that my cables are copper. No support for copper?  .... this might explain why my attempts to set the speed (e.g. "ethtool -s eno1 speed 1000 duplex full") were failing with "invalid argument", it's saying it doesn't support anything other than 10000baseT/Full....  But the docs say the card is supposed to support both fibre and copper, or at least it sounds that way... hmmm...

Comment: Do not disable autonegotiation.  Autonegotiation is a *required* part of 1000baseT and higher speeds.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet#1000BASE-T:  "Autonegotiation is a requirement for using 1000BASE-T"  See also http://etherealmind.com/ethernet-autonegotiation-works-why-how-standard-should-be-set/:  "Gigabit Ethernet must have auto-negotation ENABLED to allow negotiation of master / slave PHY relationshitwhp for clocking at the physical layer. Without negotiation the line clock will not establish correctly and physical layers problems can result."

Comment: Well, it doesn't let me either way.  :Þ

Comment: Don't mind the "supported ports: [FIBRE]", it actually works with DAC as well.

Answer (score 3):

So, I heard back from Intel. Basically, the base 82599 does not support anything less than 10 Gbps; however, manufacturers can modify it to add other kinds of support, which apparently must be what my board's manufacturer did. So I'd need to contact my board's manufacturer and figure out what would be needed to get 10/100/1000 ethernet working.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    Supports auto-negotiation: No
> ```

You need to manually set your link speed which you've already figured out

> (e.g. "ethtool -s eno1 speed 1000 duplex full") were failing with "invalid argument", it's saying it doesn't support anything other than 10000baseT/Full

This is plausible - there are 10GbE network devices out there that do not support anything except 10GbE connections (i.e. they won't negotiate down to a lower speed). Plausible, but unlikely.

Importantly you don't actually mention which exact NIC is in your computer - 82599 covers an entire class of Intel NICs. Is it connected via TwinAX DAC, or via an SFP connector?

Although this is not really an answer, it was too much for a comment - can you try a totally different operating system (say, Windows) temporarily to see if it works under a different OS?

Comment: I do not have a second operating system. As for the model, my only knowledge of the controller comes from lspci, which states "02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 10 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)" dmesg doesn't provide any information to elaborate on it. I found that when searching for what my network card via "lspci | grep -i net"; it's the only entry returned. Now here's where it gets interesting for me. You write "Is it connected via TwinAX DAC, or via an SFP connector". I've ...

Comment: never heard of either of these things before (I don't work in networking); it's connected by a standard copper twisted pair ethernet cable (XBase-T - I presume 100 or 1000Base-T). However, doing a google image search for the connectors you mentioned, I see that the they look like they would fit into a different connector on my motherboard. I do not have a networking setup designed for them, it's just a simple home ethernet networking setup.

Comment: The there is definitely something wrong with your drivers. I guess this is not news though. You can get a trial version of Windows from Microsoft.com very easily for testing.